# Probability of 2D point being in a circle where joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is bivariate normal

Tags: probability, self-study

If the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is bivariate normal with $\mu_X = \mu_Y = 0$, $\sigma_X = \sigma_Y = 9$ and $\rho = 0$, find $P(X^2 + Y^2 \leq 36)$.

I think that the double integral to evaluate is $\int_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 36}\int \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{x^2}{81} + \frac{y^2}{81})} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$. Substitute $x = r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$ and $\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$ to get a double integral using polar coordinates.

Then let $u = r^2$ so that $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}r} = r$. It's basically integrating an exponential funcion from $u = 0$ to $36$ and $\theta = 0$ to $2\pi$.

Why do I get a number greater than 1?

Comment: $\sigma_X\sigma_Y$ is missing in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks so much! Updated the factor to the left of the exponential and it worked out!